# Finding minimum difference between fit line and data points in R

Tags: r, intersection, minimum

Currently, I am trying to find a way to write a function in R that will find the yield strength of a material from a stress strain curve. I have 24 stress strain plots of specimen that were tensile tested.

Typically, the yield strength is found by taking the linear portion of the stress strain curve and offsetting it 0.2%. Where that line intersects with the original stress strain curve is known as the yield strength of a material.

I can find the slope of the linear section of the graph. What I am having trouble with is offsetting that line and finding where it intersects with the original curve.

Refer to the picture below:
[image: Yield Strength]

My stress strain plots are a discrete set of data points, so I will fit a linear curve to the first section of the graph by removing some points. After I have a linear equation, I will offset it the 0.2%. Using the offset equation, I will apply that to the corresponding stress strain curve.

I would do the absolute value of the minimum so that I get a good approximation for the intersecting point. If I don't use the absolute value then I think R will find a large negative difference between the fit and data points way off where the linear equation goes off the page.

In order to run my code quickly, please download the csv file from the Dropbox link.

[CSV File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/59z4pd8e7h8tsrg/test.csv?dl=0)

```
#Set the working directory to where you saved the CSV file and R script.
setwd("C:/your_working_directory")

#Read in the CSV
test_file <- read.csv("C:/your_working_directory/test.csv",
                      header = TRUE, 
                      quote="\"", 
                      stringsAsFactors= TRUE, 
                      strip.white = TRUE)

#Assigns the values from the stress column to a vector
stress <- test_file$stress[2:176]

#Assigns the values from the strain column to a vector
strain <- test_file$strain[2:176]

#Plotting the stress and strain, I only inlcluded the first 175 points
#so that you can see where the curve starts to
#bend as shown in the example picture. 
plot(strain, stress, main='Stress v Strain', xlab='Strain (in/in)', ylab='Stress (PSI)')

#-------------Get Slope Function Section---------------------#

#get.slope function returns the slope of the passed in values
get.slope<-function(stress,strain){
  LinearFit<- lm(stress~strain)
  Slope <- summary(LinearFit)$coefficients[2, 1]
}

#calls function to fit first degree polynomial equation, 
#notice that only the first 100 points are used where the curve is
#still fairly linear:
modulus<-get.slope(stress[1:100],strain[1:100])

LinearFit <- lm(stress~strain)
print(summary(LinearFit))
```

This is what the plot should output:
[image: Stress v Strain]

And where the red X is the point that I'm trying to estimate.
[image: Stress v Strain and yield]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stress` and `strain` from the Note at the end compute a spline approximation to the stress-strain curve (`spl`) and use `uniroot` to compute its intersection, B.

```
# calculate B, the intersection point

modulus <- coef(lm(stress ~ strain, subset = 1:100))[2] # slope

spl <- splinefun(strain, stress) # spl is a function giving stress as a function of strain
fun <- function(strain) modulus * (strain - 0.002) - spl(strain) # B[1] is root of fun
out <- uniroot(fun, range(strain))
B <- c(out$root, spl(out$root))  # x and y coords of B, the intersection

# create plot

plot(stress ~ strain, type = "l", col = "red",
     xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i",  # axes start at 0
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",  # no ticks or tick labels
     xlab = epsilon ~ "(strain, in/in)", ylab = sigma ~ "(stress)")

points(B[1], B[2], pch = 20, cex = 2, col = "lightblue") # blue dot at B

segments(0.002, 0, B[1], B[2])  # AB
segments(0, B[2], B[1], B[2], lty = 2) # horizontal dashed line segement
segments(B[1], 0, B[1], B[2], lty = 2) # vertical dashed line segment

# axis tick labels
axis(1, 0.002) # mark 0.002 on X axis
axis(1, B[1], ~ epsilon[y])
axis(2, B[2], ~ sigma[y], las = 1)

# mark O, A and B
text(B[1], B[2], "B", adj = c(-0.5, 1))
text(0.002, 0, "A", adj = c(1, -0.5))
text(0, 0, "O", adj = c(-1, -0.5))
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** The inputs used were (for future reference this is how one reproducibly provides inputs to keep everything self-contained and easily copyable into R):

```
stress <- c(113.3385421, 462.297649, 754.3743987, 873.7138964, 917.3587659, 
957.76731, 947.5992303, 962.0677743, 960.7792493, 955.4918091, 
969.4260236, 971.3544525, 965.0086849, 968.7318796, 969.209709, 
969.6165097, 969.0247115, 964.7810702, 977.008659, 975.3817792, 
974.3037574, 980.0322212, 966.6442819, 971.5307328, 975.0376129, 
984.5745059, 984.48346, 986.4060775, 1004.222656, 1003.195645, 
1040.114098, 1095.025409, 1315.958855, 1592.423499, 1872.966804, 
2152.901522, 2442.51519, 2718.843266, 3003.570806, 3271.090355, 
3549.170579, 3822.213577, 4101.431228, 4380.060633, 4648.839972, 
4922.631032, 5180.630799, 5440.223224, 5708.234808, 5951.168745, 
6197.33933, 6443.517986, 6679.028457, 6917.311952, 7159.027746, 
7387.715265, 7623.21379, 7844.363228, 8087.072456, 8318.090361, 
8537.992923, 8768.527188, 8981.64425, 9209.520427, 9422.6094, 
9624.035463, 9864.527304, 10051.87128, 10284.48604, 10497.43005, 
10717.77622, 10949.09568, 11149.25129, 11382.17503, 11584.37111, 
11795.36732, 12022.06442, 12224.53944, 12474.11263, 12677.37575, 
12886.3005, 13131.58969, 13329.81914, 13564.19282, 13787.43212, 
14004.68466, 14235.62444, 14437.42308, 14677.19785, 14903.37871, 
15135.13918, 15354.2317, 15576.63673, 15803.95985, 16018.27633, 
16248.07093, 16474.49392, 16688.64251, 16925.30236, 17137.32041, 
17358.54895, 17579.98605, 17790.69395, 18011.11179, 18228.41309, 
18436.13068, 18649.90766, 18837.8951, 19040.28747, 19216.29398, 
19414.22349, 19607.13483, 19791.43297, 19971.1885, 20159.73545, 
20348.92618, 20529.35777, 20709.53786, 20894.83492, 21071.76642, 
21243.59838, 21417.62835, 21590.91091, 21766.39697, 21929.31289, 
22094.33385, 22251.90131, 22412.12427, 22563.67302, 22700.23859, 
22844.01099, 22980.1562, 23105.12601, 23224.57722, 23338.65058, 
23449.11698, 23547.68608, 23646.64228, 23741.96956, 23831.31074, 
23910.64462, 23979.96378, 24062.2828, 24127.02416, 24186.16297, 
24259.75418, 24313.22296, 24360.72727, 24425.38727, 24463.31174, 
24517.21606, 24564.4227, 24607.92519, 24663.63008, 24689.33859, 
24743.03725, 24779.71259, 24824.05871, 24886.27435, 24890.73302, 
24951.50516, 24979.0333, 25015.69217, 25059.98954, 25077.32958, 
25141.987, 25154.45447, 25190.59419, 25236.6169, 25249.49796, 
25302.25032, 25322.93226, 25352.40432, 25388.76875)

strain <- c(0, 4e-05, 8.5e-05, 0.00011, 0.00011, 0.000115, 1e-04, 8.5e-05, 
7.5e-05, 5e-05, 4.5e-05, 3.5e-05, 3e-05, 3e-05, 2.5e-05, 3.5e-05, 
2.5e-05, 1.5e-05, 2e-05, 1e-05, 2.5e-05, 2e-05, 2.5e-05, 2e-05, 
1.5e-05, 2.5e-05, 2e-05, 2.5e-05, 3e-05, 2.5e-05, 3.5e-05, 3.5e-05, 
6.5e-05, 9.5e-05, 0.000125, 0.00015, 0.00018, 0.00021, 0.00024, 
0.000275, 3e-04, 0.00033, 0.00036, 0.00039, 0.000425, 0.00045, 
0.000475, 0.000505, 0.00053, 0.000555, 0.00058, 6e-04, 0.00062, 
0.000645, 0.000665, 0.000685, 7e-04, 0.00072, 0.000735, 0.000755, 
0.000775, 0.000795, 0.000815, 0.000825, 0.000845, 0.00086, 0.000875, 
0.000895, 0.000915, 0.00093, 0.00095, 0.000965, 0.000985, 0.001, 
0.00102, 0.00104, 0.00106, 0.00108, 0.0011, 0.00112, 0.00114, 
0.00116, 0.001185, 0.0012, 0.001225, 0.001245, 0.00127, 0.00129, 
0.00131, 0.001335, 0.001355, 0.001385, 0.001405, 0.00143, 0.00145, 
0.001475, 0.0015, 0.001525, 0.001545, 0.00157, 0.001595, 0.001615, 
0.001645, 0.001665, 0.00169, 0.001715, 0.00174, 0.001765, 0.001785, 
0.001815, 0.001835, 0.00186, 0.001885, 0.001905, 0.001935, 0.001955, 
0.00198, 0.00201, 0.00204, 0.00207, 0.002095, 0.002125, 0.00216, 
0.00219, 0.00222, 0.002255, 0.00229, 0.00233, 0.002365, 0.00241, 
0.00245, 0.0025, 0.002545, 0.002595, 0.002645, 0.002695, 0.00275, 
0.002805, 0.00286, 0.002925, 0.00299, 0.003055, 0.003125, 0.0032, 
0.00328, 0.003365, 0.00345, 0.003535, 0.00363, 0.00373, 0.003825, 
0.003915, 0.00401, 0.004095, 0.004195, 0.004285, 0.004375, 0.00447, 
0.00456, 0.00466, 0.004755, 0.00485, 0.00495, 0.00505, 0.005145, 
0.005245, 0.005345, 0.005445, 0.005555, 0.005665, 0.005775, 0.00589, 
0.006005, 0.006115)
```

Comment: Okay, I wrote a much smaller version of the code that illustrates what I have so far. All you need to do is download the csv file so that you can read it in with the r script.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! So, B is a vector of length 2, the first value being the x intercept and the second value is the y intercept?

Comment: I see that you updated your code slightly. When I use your new chunk, I'm getting an error: _"Error in if (!is.numeric(lower) || !is.numeric(upper) || lower >= upper) stop("lower < upper  is not fulfilled") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"_ but I don't see any if statements in your code.

Comment: It works for me with the input in the Note.  Be sure that there are no NAs in your input data.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following code:

```
# Create data for example
strain <- seq(0, 2, by = 0.1)
stress <- sin(strain)

plot(strain, stress, type = "l")

# Fit a linear model and plot the fitted values
fit <-lm(strain ~ stress)
lines(strain, fitted(fit))

# Find the distance on x-axis
dist <- unname(-coef(fit)[1]/coef(fit)[2])
dist
#[1] 0.1197057
text(y = 0, x = dist, labels = round(dist, 2))


# Find point of intersection of curves
indx <- which(diff(stress > fitted(fit))!=0)
strain[indx]
#[1] 0.1986693

text(y = strain[indx], x = stress[indx], labels = strain[indx])
```

[image]